# Error installing openstack on centos

Tags: puppet, openstack

In order to setup openstack using centos 7 with virtualbox, i got the following error while running `packstack --allinone`

```
Pre installing Puppet and discovering hosts' details[ ERROR ]

ERROR : Failed to run remote script, stdout:
stderr: Warning: Permanently added '192.168.56.24' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
+ trap t ERR
+ facter -p
++ t
++ exit 12
```

I have only one host : 192.168.56.24 (where i run the installation)
Any ideas ?

Comment: Try disabling the host checking for the ssh agent so the warning is not thrown and you do not get a false fatal stop.

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving this is to edit `~/.ssh/config`

and add:

```
Host 192.168.0.*
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

This link should also be very useful even though it is on ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/87449/how-to-disable-strict-host-key-checking-in-ssh